# parsing script never ends

Tags: powershell, parsing, infinite-loop

i have the following script but it does never end executing.

what could be the issue ? I tried to debug it but apparently it works correctly with a single file, but when I throw it against a folder full of content fails.

```
$path = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$files = Get-ChildItem "$path\CodeForCertification\5_SourceCode\*" -Include *.c,*.h -Recurse | where{ 
        ! $_.PSIsContainer 
}#$PSScriptRoot

ForEach ($file in $files){

    $data = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName
    $feature = Get-Content "$path\Disabled_Features.txt"    
    #[System.ArrayList]$Modifier
    $nl=[Environment]::NewLine
    $Modifier=@()
    $flag=0
    $data = $data | ForEach-Object -Begin {
        $ignore = $false; $levels = 0 
    } -Process {
        for($counter=0; $counter -lt $feature.Count; $counter++){
            $parse = $feature[$counter]
            if($_ -match "^#ifdef $parse" -And $flag -eq '0') {
                $ignore = $true
                $flag = 1;
            }
        }
        if($ignore) {
            if ($_ -match "^#ifdef") {
                $levels++ 
            }elseif ($_ -match "#endif") {
                if($levels -ge 1) {
                    $levels--
                    if($levels -eq '0'){
                        $ignore = $false
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }else {
            $flag=0
            $temp=$_
            $_
            $Modifier+="$temp"
        }
    }
    $data | Out-File $file.FullName
}
```

Comment: Yeah, why not?...

Comment: Do you have some sample files we can test with? Your disabledFeatures and a scrubbed source code file? Have you tried putting in some output lines between files so you know it is moving on? How are you measuring the loops lack of progress? Would be nice to know what this code is supposed to do in case there is a better approach.

Comment: Did you debug in PowerShell ISE with breakpoints? Your code could be simply slow, partly because you re-read the txt file on every iteration and use Get-Content in the default mode which is extremely slow on huge files with lots of lines.

Comment: The txt file only contains multiple line entries such as STRING1 STRING2 (In separate lines) and the source code is just some .c file with paragraphs #ifdef STRING2 "block of code" #endif, for example. I am fearing it is just the method which is slow. I appreciate optimizations. P.d.: yes I debugged with ISE powershell with breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Jackson, let's solve your problem before you enter some kind of question spam filter ;-)

Consider this (just put it somewhere at the start of your script):

```
function RemoveUndesiredFeatures([string[]]$lines,[string[]]$undesiredFeatures)
{    
    $inIgnoreBlock = $false
    $nestingLevel = 0

    foreach ($line in $lines)
    {
        if ($inIgnoreBlock)
        {
            # Only search for nested blocks and end of block
            if ($line -like "#ifdef*")
            {
                $nestingLevel++
            }
            elseif ($line -like "#endif*")
            {
                $nestingLevel--
            }

            if ($nestingLevel -eq 0)
            {
                $inIgnoreBlock = $false
            }
        }
        else
        {
            # Search for undesired feature
            $isIfdefMatch = $line -match "#ifdef (?<feature>\w+)"

            if ($isIfdefMatch -and ($Matches.feature -in $undesiredFeatures))
            {
                # Ignore Feature
                $inIgnoreBlock = $true
                $nestingLevel++
            }
            else
            {
                # Output line
                $line
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Here is my example to use it:

```
$undesiredFeatures = @("F1","F2") # Just as example. Get-Content on a file with features is also fine

$files = Get-ChildItem *.c,*.h -Recurse # Again, just as example

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $lines = Get-Content $file.FullName

    $changedLines = RemoveUndesiredFeatures $lines $undesiredFeatures

    if ($changedLines.Count -ne $lines.Count)
    {
        # Features were removed. Write out changed file (to a different file to preserve my test files)
        Set-Content -Value $changedLines -Path "$($file.FullName).changed"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give you a feedback on monday

Comment: After several adaptations worked like a charm. My thanks Toni.
Just FYI, -In fails to get the value, so that I had to use -Contain operator for the feature match.

Comment: OK, for `-in` to work, the right side must be an array and the left side must be verbatim contained in that array. This should be the case if you get a list of features with a simple `Get-Content` of a file where each feature is one line (beware of extra spaces though). The `-contains` operator works exactly the same, only with left and right side swapped (array left, search value right). So I'm a bit confused about how you solved it that way, but as long as it works ...